# react-native run-android "Could not install the app on the device..."

Tags: react-native

**Scenario**

Attemping to run `$ react-native run-android` results in

> Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   /Users/Jackson/Sites/fnmultiapptest/node_modules (11ms) JS server
>   already running. Building and installing the app on the device (cd
>   android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
>
> Could not install the app on the
>   device, read the error above for details. Make sure you have an
>   Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your
>   Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

**Relevant Info**

I can run my app fine from Android Studio if I run it on an emulator. I can also connect to the react-native "Metro Bundler".

`adb devices` reports back with emulator device id.

`ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_PATH` are present and correct

**Question**

Why can't I install my app to the emulator when using `react-native run-android` if it works fine via Android Studio (which also uses ADB)

**Extra Notes**

- Working on a MBP w 12.14 Mojave
- Android Studio version 3.2.1
- Emulator OS is 8.0 (api 26)

Comment: Which is your emulator's OS version?

Comment: @JoseVf Using 8.0 (26) - I also added that info to my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seemed like a blanket try/catch error message so I dug in the the command mentioned `cd android && ./gradlew installDebug`

And when running that I saw `gradlew permission denied`

So I ran `chmod +x ./android/gradlew` and violá

Comment: chmod +x ./android/grandlew is not working, chmod +x ./android/gradlew should work as expected

Comment: I always forgot chmod :(

Answer (score 0):

you might check the permissions on android/gradlew

they should be 755 not 644

run

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

inside your app root folder
then open your terminal again and run

```
react-native run-android
```

and it should work again.